# Javascript radio buttons mouseover move images with math.random used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Kind of new to programming to general and messing around with some JS. I’m trying to get some understanding and help to fix this. I’ve been to the library, trying to figure this out.

What I’m trying to do is have 3 radio buttons. I named them like small, medium, large and have a div in the middle. The div is suppose to be in the middle of the screen. The person selects a displacement, delta, from the radio buttons. The users mouses over the coloured div, the div would then move to a new location that is random (I’m thinking random() method), then the displacement between [delta -5, delta +5].

How do I go on fixing this? Can you help? Thanks.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Choose step size:</h2>
1 px <input type="radio" id="small" name="move" value="1" checked="checked"><br>
10 px <input type="radio" id="medium" name="move" value="10"><br>
100 px <input type="radio" id="large" name="move" value="100"><br>

<div class='a' id="mainDiv" onmouseover=" move();"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function(){  
  $('#mainDiv').mouseover(function(){
      var stepSize = parseInt( $('input[type=radio][name=move]:checked').val() );

      var pos = $( this ).position();
      var left = parseInt( pos.left );
      var top = parseInt( pos.top );

      var new_left = left + stepSize;
      var new_top = top + stepSize;    

      $( this ).css('left', new_left + 'px' );
      $( this ).css('top', new_top + 'px' );
  });});
</script>
<style>
div.a {
  width: 80px;
  height:80px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you need :

```js
$( document ).ready( function(){  
  $('#mainDiv').mouseover(function(){
      var stepSize = parseInt( $('input[type=radio][name=move]:checked').val() );

      var pos = $( this ).position();
      var left = parseInt( pos.left );
      var top = parseInt( pos.top );
      
      var new_left = left + (getRandomIntInclusive(0,stepSize) * [-1,1][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)] );
      var new_top = top + (getRandomIntInclusive(0,stepSize) * [-1,1][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)] );    

      $( this ).css('left', new_left + 'px' );
      $( this ).css('top', new_top + 'px' );
  });});

function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
div.a {
  width: 80px;
  height:80px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Choose step size:</h2>
1 px <input type="radio" id="small" name="move" value="1" checked="checked"><br>
10 px <input type="radio" id="medium" name="move" value="10"><br>
100 px <input type="radio" id="large" name="move" value="100"><br>

<div class='a' id="mainDiv" onmouseover=" move();"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jQuery in your project ?

```js
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```